# Protocol declaration ends with semicolon?

Tags: objective-c

```
@protocol ZZCapturePipelineDelegate;
@protocol ZZMediaManagerProtocol;
@protocol ZZCapturePipelineProtocol <NSObject>
...
@end
```

I understand `ZZCapturePipelineProtocol` is the protocol being declared here. However I have never seen the syntax with multiple @protocol in one file. Since the first two protocols ends with semicolon, I am assuming the their purposes are to import or reference to their respective .h files?

Comment: It most likely means that somewhere in the `...` part, there's a pointer-to-an-object that implements one or both of those protocols.  The question would be much improved if you showed the line(s) that use those protocols.

Answer (score 3):

The two ones are called `forward declarations` - i.e. you inform the compiler that the protocols exist, but without importing the headers where they were defined. This improves the build time because the compiler doesn't have to insert+compile the content of other headers.

You can find out more details [here](http://railsware.com/blog/2013/08/09/using-forward-declaration-in-your-objective-c-projects/).

Comment: So it's an indicator that the implementation will include all of the those protocols?

Comment: It doesn't actually improve build time nowadays. It's a way to solve cyclical dependencies.

Comment: @Yonk Nope, forward declaration has only one meaning. `@protocol ZZCapturePipelineDelegate;` says `ZZCapturePipelineDelegate` is a protocol. It doesn't say anything about implementation. There are also forward declarations for classes or functions.

Comment: @Yonk it's an indicator that the .m files will likely import the header. It's not a guarantee, though.

Comment: Same, as more often seen in Objective-C with `@class someClass;`, since function forward declaration are more needed in C.